# How create a notification in notifications bar when ACTION_BATTERY_LOW?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

i want to create a simple notification when `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`.. What i want is start a notificaion in the status bar when the popup of battery low comes up. I've tried in this way:
In the onCreate

```
this.registerReceiver(this.batteryLowNotifi, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW));
```

And then:

```
private void checkPref(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                TutorialNotification.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TutorialNotification.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
          checkPref(intent);
      }
    }
```

But nothing happen. Any help?Thanks

Comment: you should probably register the reciver in manifest and start a service and should use the service to compose the notification

Comment: In the manifest i've already registred the receiver but nothing..

Comment: then start a service to launch the notification from the reciver

Comment: What do you mean? I thought that calling the `checkPref(intent);` in the receive the notification started..

Comment: have you tried debugging??

Comment: simply logcat say anything.

Comment: try 2 log each point so you will understand were all has the code come to and figure out were it goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reciver class

```
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    // Restart service every 30 min
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 30*1000*4;//1800000 ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent service = new Intent(context, service.class);
context.startService(service);
}}
```

service class

```
public class service extends Service {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
      @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
      }

      @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
  mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
checkPref();
}
@Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

      }

private void checkPref(){ 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                                service.this);
                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
                notificationBuilder.setContentText("Context");
                notificationBuilder.setTicker("TickerText");
                notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_icon);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, service.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                notificationIntent, 0);

                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

                notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                mNotificationManager.notify(1,
                                notificationBuilder.build());
    }   }
```

register the reciver and service in manifest

```
  <receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
 <service android:name="service" >
        </service>
```